# How to display remote data into ionic-view?

Tags: web-services, ionic4, fetch-api

I'm trying to display my fetched remote data, from IonicPage to template view using ng-repeat.

How to display my fetched remote data into ionic html view?

Running Ionic-4. 
I’ve tried to log fetched remote data, web call is ok. It seems template-view load before fetched-remote-data.

1 - Following method load data

```
  public onLoadData(){
    this.http.get(this.cfg.fetchPlatformUrl()).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.remoteData = data;
    });
  }
```

2 - Following method get data from IonicPage variable

```
public getRemoteExerciseData(){
    return this.exerciseVideos;      
  }
```

3 - its template view code does not listing as i expected.

```html
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>
         <b>Exercise List</b></i>
      </ion-label>  
    </ion-list-header>

    <!-- START - ISSUE IDENTIFIER -->
      <ion-item ng-repeat="ex in getRemoteExerciseData()">
          Video 1
          <ion-chip color="success">
              <ion-label>V</ion-label>
              <ion-icon name="happy" color="success"></ion-icon>
          </ion-chip>
          <ion-chip color="danger">
              <ion-label>X</ion-label>
              <ion-icon name="sad" color="danger"></ion-icon>
          </ion-chip>
      </ion-item>
    <!-- END - ISSUE IDENTIFIER -->
  </ion-list>
```

I expect see the list of fetched remote data, but the actual template view show only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exercise List**

```
<!-- START - ISSUE IDENTIFIER -->
  <ion-item *ngFor="ex in getRemoteExerciseData()">
      Video 1
      <ion-chip color="success">
          <ion-label>V</ion-label>
          <ion-icon name="happy" color="success"></ion-icon>
      </ion-chip>
      <ion-chip color="danger">
          <ion-label>X</ion-label>
          <ion-icon name="sad" color="danger"></ion-icon>
      </ion-chip>
  </ion-item>
<!-- END - ISSUE IDENTIFIER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For latests Angular versions, you should use [ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)